# Why miniupnpc Python module throwing error on ufw activation

Tags: python, pip, dns, ip, router

here my problem , i am trying to get my public ip address using a python module called : miniupnpc
it is working fine using the following python code

```
# pip install miniupnpc
import miniupnpc

u = miniupnpc.UPnP()
u.discoverdelay = 200
u.discover()
u.selectigd()
externalIP = format(u.externalipaddress())

with open("/home/stack/Desktop/Python/my_external_ip.txt" , "w") as x :
    y = x.write(externalIP)
```

but when i activate the firewall using this command it throw this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 8, in 
u.selectigd()
Exception: No UPnP device discovered

Thanks for help

NB : i dont need to use external api to get my public ip but sending request to my router

i have expect geting my public ip address but the code throw error on ufw activation